# Work around for template specialization bug in VC++12?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I have some code written for Clang 3.2 that I'm trying to port to run in VC++12.  Clang 3.2+ and GCC 4.8 have no problem with it, but VC++12 complains.  Here's a minimal snippet that produces the issue:

```
template <int(*ptr)()>
class foo {};

template<int N>
int ReturnsN() { return N; }

template<int N>
class bar {
  typedef foo<ReturnsN<N>> fooN; 
};
```

Now I'm pretty sure this is a compiler bug (but please let me know if it isn't!)  The error given is:

```
'specialization' : cannot convert from 'int (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'int (__cdecl *)(void)'
```

So does anyone know a decent work around?  It appears the compiler is convinced that the specialized function isn't completely defined.

EDIT:  I should also note I've tried this with both the stock compiler, and the November 2013 CTP.  Both have the same problem.

Comment: I'm dying to know if the `inline` removed makes any difference whatsoever.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh sorry, it doesn't.  I thought it did, and left it in from my test project.  Will edit my question.

Comment: And I assume you tried `foo<&ReturnsN<N>>` also ? (if that worked I'd start selling my MS stock right now). (also, I see no specialization here; only instantiation).

Comment: @WhozCraig I did try that, unfortunately.  I believe any viable workaround has to emulate the template parameter somehow since replacing `<N>` with a literal, or a visible `static const int` works fine.

Comment: I don't have mine up and running at the moment. Does VC2012/2013 implement template aliasing?

Comment: @WhozCraig It does, but that didn't help.  I found a hack that works, thanks for your ideas!

Comment: All of this really is at namespace scope, no class members except the obvious `class bar<N>`, correct?

Comment: @BenVoigt Correct.  I'm compiling the above with an empty `main` and that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sad workaround and i suggest you submit a bug report to [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) :

```
template < int (*)() >
class foo {};

template<int N>
int ReturnsN( ) { return N; }

template<int N>
class bar {
    static int myReturnsN() { return ReturnsN<N>; }
    using fooN = foo< myReturnsN >;
};
```

Comment: I just found the same workaround!  I'll give you the points though, thanks for the help.  [Here's the bug report as well.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/816952/specialization-of-function-template-cannot-be-passed-as-template-parameter)

Comment: VS2013 is sick… And this one is not even related to c++11 support like fancy parameter pack expansion…

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is curious, I found a workaround that's a little ugly.  Basically just need to add a static member function to obscure the function, so it doesn't try to resolve the function specialization while also resolving the function pointer template parameter:

```
template <int(*ptr)()>
class foo {};

template<int N>
int ReturnsN() { return N; }

template<int N>
class bar {
private:
  static int Hack() {
    return ReturnsN<N>();
  }
public:
  typedef foo<Hack> fooN;
};
```

This compiles in all of VS2012, VS2013 and VS2013 November CTP.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible workaround is to make `ReturnsN` function static member function of a class template:

```
template <int(*)()>
class foo;

template <int N>
struct Wrapper {
    static int ReturnsN() { return N; }
};

template <int N>
class bar {
    typedef foo<Wrapper<N>::ReturnsN> fooN; 
};
```

This code compiles fine with VC++ 2013.